# java sign jar show java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.security.mscapi")

Tags: java, jar, applet

I am use sign jar applet to sign pdf but when sign it has error

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.security.mscapi")
>     at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkPackageAccessHelper(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
>   ...
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

My jar has signed

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs .\target\SignApplet40-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar   

s     599534 Wed Feb 21 08:43:46 ICT 2018 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

      [entry was signed on 2/21/18 8:43 AM]
      X.509, CN=xxx
      [certificate is valid from 1/19/18 7:00 AM to 1/20/19 6:59 AM]
      X.509, CN=COMODO RSA Code Signing CA, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
      [certificate is valid from 5/9/13 7:00 AM to 5/9/28 6:59 AM]
      X.509, CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
      [certificate is valid from 1/19/10 7:00 AM to 1/19/38 6:59 AM]
      [CertPath not validated: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors] 
...
sm     40426 Wed Feb 21 08:43:36 ICT 2018 com/itextpdf/testutils/CompareTool.class

      [entry was signed on 2/21/18 8:43 AM]
      X.509, CN=xxx
      [certificate is valid from 1/19/18 7:00 AM to 1/20/19 6:59 AM]
      X.509, CN=COMODO RSA Code Signing CA, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
      [certificate is valid from 5/9/13 7:00 AM to 5/9/28 6:59 AM]
      X.509, CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
      [certificate is valid from 1/19/10 7:00 AM to 1/19/38 6:59 AM]
      [CertPath not validated: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors]


  s = signature was verified 
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.
Warning: 
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
```

Here is my code get cer from usb token

```
public String signByToken(TokenInfor tokenInfo)
            throws Exception, IOException, GeneralSecurityException, DocumentException
    {
        byte[] pdfByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(tokenInfo.getContentToSign());
;
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
            public Object run() {
                // privileged code goes here, for example:
                Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
                return null; // nothing to return
            }
        });

        SunMSCAPI providerMSCAPI = (SunMSCAPI) AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
            public Object run() {
                // privileged code goes here, for example:
                SunMSCAPI provider = new SunMSCAPI();
                Security.addProvider(provider);
                return provider; // nothing to return
            }
        });

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
        ks.load(null, null);

        String alias = "";
        Enumeration oEnum = ks.aliases();
        while(oEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            String _alias = (String)oEnum.nextElement();
            x509Cert = (X509Certificate)ks.getCertificate(_alias);
            if(x509Cert.getSerialNumber().toString(16).equalsIgnoreCase(tokenInfo.getSelectedCertificate())) {
                alias = _alias;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (alias == "")
            throw new Exception("Can not found token. \n \n Please insert token with serial number : " + tokenInfo.getSelectedCertificate());

        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, null);
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);

        byte[] outPdfByteArray = sign(pdfByteArray, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1,
                providerMSCAPI.getName(), MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);

        return Base64.encodeBase64String(outPdfByteArray);
    }
```

Comment: So you need to grant your applet that permission.

Comment: @EJP is there anyway to allow applet without edit .java.policy?